# Writing or updating a value on swiftyjson

Tags: json, xcode, swift2, swifty-json

I'm trying to write o set values on swiftyjason using Swift 2.0.
Right now, I can read values, but I'm not sure how you to write into the json files or change a value. I prefer to write a value. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You should parse the JSON to make objects (like classes or structs containing properties), and then you can modify/use/manage these objects - and if needed, you encode these objects back to JSON again for data export. // JSON should be used as a format to transport data, in and out, not a format for using data in your app directly. You don't have to "write into the json files".

Comment: THanks! very help full!